# Why does the for loop in my code restart automatically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to output the pascal triangle. So i stored the previous output in an array(for ex:1,2,1).Then i'm trying to obtain sum of two elements in array(like array[0]+array[1] then array[1]+array[2]).But the loop which i use for getting the sum restarts on it's own (i.e after o is equal to array.length-1 o becomes equal to zero.

Also any help with proper code formatting and how i could do this in a better way is welcome.

I have tried setting array length to zero when the variable o is equal to array length but then too loop starts to run again from zero.

```js
var count=0,sum=0;
let arr=[],arr1=[],arr2=[];
//For Rows
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  //For Spaces
  for (var k = 4; k >= i; k--) {
    document.querySelector('#a').innerHTML += " &nbsp;";
  }
  //For addition logic (This Restarts automatically)
  for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    if (j == 1 || j == i) {
      document.querySelector('#a').innerHTML += " " + 1;
    } else {
      for (let o = 0; o < arr2.length; o++) {
        sum += parseInt(arr2[o]);
        if (o % 2 == 1 && i > 3) {
          document.querySelector('#a').innerHTML += " " + sum;
          sum = parseInt(arr2[o]);
        }
      }
      document.querySelector('#a').innerHTML += " " + sum;
    }
    count += 1;
  }
  if (i > 1) {
    sum = 0;
    arr.length = 0, arr1.length = 0, arr2.length = 0;
    arr.push(document.querySelector('#a').innerText);
    arr1 = Array.from(arr[0]);
    arr2 = arr1.filter(rem)

    function rem(value) {
      return value > 0;
    }
    var temp = 0;
    while (temp < count - i) {
      arr2.shift();
      temp++;
    }
  }
  document.querySelector('#a').innerHTML += "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="a"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
       1
      1 1
     1 2 1
    1 3 3 1   
Expected Result
       1
      1 1
     1 2 1
  1 3 3 6 3 1
 Actual Result
```

Comment: At first glance, the line  `sum = parseInt(arr2[o]);` looks weird - shouldn't it be  `+=` ?  Next time, don't use o as a variable name, it can make code VERY hard to read in some fonts.

Comment: i tried using += it lead me to  1 3 6 9 12 1..this makes things go worse..   edit:   about variable o i will keep that in mind ..I'm a newbie at coding so i know i might have many things incorrect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a loop for getting the wanted length of the array and another for calculating the sum of two elements of the array.

This approach starts with a single element and takes for every round one at start and one at the end and all other value from the array.

```js
var length = 4,
    array = [1],
    temp,
    i,
    element = document.querySelector('#a');

element.innerHTML += array.join(' ');

while (array.length < length) {
    temp = [1];
    for (i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        temp.push(array[i] + array[i + 1]);
    }

    temp.push(1);
    array = temp;
    element.innerHTML += '<br>' + array.join(' ');
}
```

```html
<div id="a" style="text-align: center"></div>
```

Comment: sorry, not answer your question, but you take some strange filtering of an array with only one item and some conversion which is not necessary. The main advidce to use the data saparated from the view and render the data for the view and take the data for further operations, not the rendered view.